# Creating sparse matrix within a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I want to make a sparse matrix from a graph which is stored in an Mx2 matrix:

```
for i = 1:m
    adj = sparse(Graph(i,1), Graph(i,2), 1);
end
```

But `adj` only keeps one value.  I don't know how big `adj` will be prior to the loop. 
How can I tell MATLAB to create this sparse matrix?

Comment: `sparse(Graph(:,1), Graph(:,2), 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `for` loop is necessary.  The [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function takes in a vector of non-zero row locations, a vector of non-zero column locations and a vector of non-zero values.  If all of the values are the same, you can simply use a scalar value to initialize all of them at once.

Simply do this<sup>1</sup>:

```
adj = sparse(Graph(:,1), Graph(:,2), 1);
```

This accesses all of the row locations with `Graph(:,1)`, the column locations with `Graph(:,2)` and finally we initialize all values at these locations to 1.

This is also assuming that you have non-duplicate row and column locations in `Graph`.  If you do have duplicate row and column locations, the non-zero values defined at these locations are accumulated into the same locations.  For example, if we had three instances of `(6,3)` in our matrix, the output at this location in the `sparse` matrix would be 3.

---

<sup>1. Credit goes to Luis Mendo for initially proposing the answer</sup>

Comment: Also worth pointing out the accumulation behavior when there are duplicate entries